# how to properly register a registry key on windows server?

Tags: key, windows-server-2008-r2, regedit, registrykey

hello I will explain my problem.
During installation I try to register a new registry key in the following path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ Software \ mykey
```

but once I analyze the result, my key is here!

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ Wow6432Node \ Software \ mykey
```

Why? I do not understand ..
Thank you in advance for your answer ^ ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only cases this happens that i have personally seen is, when it is added from an application build for a specific architecture. (e.g. 32bit, while the os is 64bit)

How are you adding the file?

[Edit]

A link to some information about this topic:
http://www.typemock.com/blog/2008/07/31/registry-on-windows-64-bit-double-your-pleasure/

Comment: Yes I actually created my registry key when a 'MSI package is installed.
This will install an asp.net web application in the directory 'c: \ \ inetpub \ www \

But how to change this?

Comment: Can't you recompile it as x64? i am not very familiar with MSI packages but that would be my guess.

Comment: No sorry this is I prefer to compile 32 bit (x86) because I prefer to keep backward compatibility with the architecture 32 and 64 bit

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem right now then? cant you retreive the key because the path is changed by windows or.. did you just want to know the explaination of why it happened?

Comment: As well I have another application that is used to update my web application that relies on the registry key given to the installation path.
Vai but I just open it as a condition I think:

if (Register.openKey ("...."). exist)
{

   doUpdate
}
else if (Register.openKey ("...."). exist)
{
  doUpdate
}

Can a special and fast but basically I want to like her ^ ^

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help ! I have marked this answer like a good answer ^^